# Ubuntu Gnome download page

Tags: downloads

where can I get the official download page for Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.03? My page keep going to wikiubuntu, is that a secure page?

Comment: https://ubuntugnome.org/download/ Please note the `https`.

Comment: @MichaelBay lol, the https got truncated :P (well for the display anyway, the actual link still has the HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the official link

https://ubuntugnome.org/download/